# Calculate Jacobian Matrix of LSTM Model - Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, model, lstm

I have a trained LSTM model with 1 LSTM Layer and 3 Dense layers. I am using it for a sequence to One prediction. I have 4 input variables and 1 output variable. I am using the values of the last 20 timesteps to predict the next value of my output variable. The architecture of the model is shown below

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = 120, activation ='relu', return_sequences = False,input_shape = 
(train_in.shape[1],5)))
    
model.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

The shapes of training input and training output are as shown below

```
train_in.shape , train_out.shape
((89264, 20, 5), (89264,))
```

I want to calculate the jacobian matrix for this model.
Say, Y = f(x1,x2,x3,x4) is the representation of the above neural network where:
Y -- Output variable of the trained model, f -- Is the function representing the Model; x1,x2,x3,x4 --input parameters.

How can I calculate the Jacobian Matrix?? Please share your thoughts on this. Also any valuable references if you know any.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

you might want to take a look at `tf.GradientTape` in tensorflow. [Gradient tape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) is very simple way to auto-differentiate your computation. And the link has some basic example.

However your model is already quite big. If you have `n` parameters, your jacobian will have `n*n` values. I believe your model probably already has more than 10000 parameters. You might need to make it smaller.

Comment: Hello @Leo , Thank you for responding. But as I want to take the Jacobian of the output w.r.t the input parameters, it would not be a great problem.....As I have only 4 input parameters, I might be getting 4*4 matrix.....Isn't it soo??

Comment: Hie @Leo, please check my answer below...I found a way to do it..Thank you for responding :)

Comment: You are right, I think your solution is working, I thought you were computing it with respect to the weights instead of the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get the Jacobian matrix for LSTM model output with respect to the input. I am posting it here so that it might help someone in the future. Please share if there is any better or more simple way to do the same

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution() #This will enable eager execution which is must.

tf.executing_eagerly() #check if eager execution is enabled or not. Should give "True"

data = pd.read_excel("FileName or Location ")
#My data is in the from of dataframe with 127549 rows and 5 columns(127549*5)

a = data[:20]  #shape is (20,5)
b = data[50:70] # shape is (20,5)
A = [a,b]  # making a list
A = np.array(A) # convert into array size (2,20,5) 

At = tf.convert_to_tensor(A, np.float32) #convert into tensor
At.shape # TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(20), Dimension(5)])

model = load_model('EKF-LSTM-1.h5') # Load the trained model
# I have a trained model which is shown in the question above. 
# Output of this model is a single value

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True,watch_accessed_variables=True) as tape:

tape.watch(At)
y1 = model(At) #defining your output as a function of input variables
print(y1,type(y1)

#output 
tf.Tensor([[0.04251503],[0.04634088]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=float32) <class 
'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>

jacobian=tape.jacobian(y1,At) #jacobian of output w.r.t both inputs
jacobian.shape
```

## Outupt

```
TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(1), Dimension(2), Dimension(20), Dimension(5)])
```

Here I calculated Jacobian w.r.t 2 inputs each of size (20,5). If you want to calculate w.r.t to only one input of size (20,5), then use this

```
jacobian=tape.jacobian(y1,At[0]) #jacobian of output w.r.t only 1st input in 'At'
jacobian.shape
```

## Output

```
TensorShape([Dimension(1), Dimension(1), Dimension(1), Dimension(20), Dimension(5)])
```

Comment: Hey, I think this is the way to go, you are missing the indentation (tabs) after the with statement though. Best, Leo